# Converting/scaling a voltage range ([0v - 5v] to [-5v - +5v])

Tags: voltage, scaling, negative

Can anyone explain how one would convert one voltage range to another? I'm going to need to convert a range of 0 to +5 volts into a range of -5 to +5 volts. How would this be accomplished? Thanks!

Comment: So which one should we use Terje's or Kortuk's?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For working with power conversions rather than signal -

You can use various integrated circuits for this job, they're commonly referred to as [Dc to DC converters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC-to-DC_converter), there's also a range of ways to do the conversion such as [Charge pumps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge_pump).

[Here's a bunch of different DC to DC converters](http://www.rapidonline.com/Electrical-Power/Power-Supplies/DC-DC-Converter-ICs) they have various different current ratings, some step the voltage up, some step down and others convert between positive and negative values.

[This is a nice charge pump IC](http://www.maxim-ic.com/datasheet/index.mvp/id/1140) that can double or invert a voltage with the minimum of external components. You could even use a [555 timer to convert a voltage to a negative](http://www.aaroncake.net/circuits/vinvertr.asp)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am giving a +1, i am not sure if he wants something for power, or if it is a signal, you did power, i did signal.

Comment: I've also had success with CMOS voltage converters (http://www.national.com/mpf/LM/LMC7660.html#Overview) they're easy to use but limited in their usefulness

Comment: Thanks guys, this gives me a lot to go with - I'll check it all out.

Comment: So are you trying to make dual power supplies Greg?

Comment: No, doing some work with a DAC-based idea, where I'll need to scale the voltage output.

Comment: I thought so, I was confused as to why you took an answer that was showing you how to get different power rails over one that scales the range. I think they are both right, but for different questions.

Answer (score 10):

There are many ways to do this, the easiest I think would be a summing op-amp configuration.

I want to try using this ascii system, lets see how it does. This is a circuit that does what you want.

```
          -5V
           |
          .-.
          | |
          | |2K           2K_
          '-'       .----|___|----.
           |        |             |
           |        |             |
           '--------o             |
                    |      +Pwr   |
       ___          |    |\|      |
input-|___|---------o----|-\      |
       1K                |  >-----o----Output
                    .----|+/
                    |    |/|
                   GND     -Pwr

(created by AACircuit v1.28.6 beta 04/19/05 www.tech-chat.de)
```

So, it takes the input, doubles it and subtracts 5 V.

This will make 2.5V become 0V, 0V becomes -5V, and 5V stays 5V.

It does it linearly over the range, this can be valuable if it is a signal that needs to be spread over a new range.

Hope this helped.

Comment: This solution is for a signal, if you want to power a system with it, i may have missunderstood you.

Comment: Cheers for pointing that out, I missed that one - doh!

Comment: Nice diagram - they look kinda retro!

Comment: They are awesome, want links? http://chiphacker.com/questions/1024/uploading-schematics-for-chip-hacker/2537#2537

Comment: That is how I learned about it, and I think I love it.

Comment: I would have assumed he is looking for a way to convert a signal since he was talking about a voltage range.

Comment: That was my assumption, but the beautiful part of this board is that multiple people respond and we covered the options.

Answer (score 1):

```
          +5V
           |
          .-.
          | |
          | |2K           2K_
          '-'       .----|___|----.
           |        |             |
           |        |             |
           '--------o             |
                    |      +Pwr   |
                    |    |\|      |
                    .----|-\      |
                         |  >-----o----Output
input--------------------|+/
                         |/|
                           -Pwr

(created by AACircuit v1.28.6 beta 04/19/05 www.tech-chat.de)
```

This will make 2.5V become 0V, 0V becomes -5V, and 5V stays 5V.

The circuit posted by Kortuk will invert the input resulting in a mapping from [0v -> 5v] to [+5v -> -5v] instead of [0v -> 5v] to [-5v -> +5v].

Here is a [simulation](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+10.634267539816555+50+5+50%0Aa+256+240+384+240+0+15+-15+1000000+4.849953000939981+4.85%0A172+256+256+208+256+0+6+4.85+5+0+0+0.5+%252B+Voltage%0AO+384+240+432+240+1%0Ar+256+224+160+224+0+2000%0Aw+256+224+256+144+0%0Aw+384+240+384+144+0%0Ar+256+144+384+144+0+2000%0AR+160+224+112+224+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0A).